# MSSQL record date/time auto delete

Tags: sql-server, datetime, records

I want to delete records from a db table based on a time-stamp for each record. I would like to have it automatically delete records compared to a date/time interval without user intervention or admin intervention.

What would be the best way to go about this, I could create a process that runs in the background that does checks but that is extra work I want to avoid? Is there any libraries/web services I could use as templates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) can do this for you.

Simply create a job with a regular schedule and the SQL you want to run. There is an easy to use wizard interface for job creation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sql JOB with below query:

UPDATE [dbo].[User] WITH (ROWLOCK) 
SET active_flag=0 where lastlogindt <  DATEADD(Day,-90,GETDATE())